# Java program that loops a curl command thru several addresses

Tags: java, curl

in a bit of a bind here.

What I am working on is a program that checks our site and returns the data using Spring's RestTemplate, then place the output in a temporary file.

The problem I am running into is that we have to check several addresses with the same hostname but different mappings (website.com/a/1, website.com/a/2, website.com/b/1 etc. )

So I'm thinking I have to have the addresses passed as a parameter that loops thru curl command each time. I'm just not sure how to accomplish this.

Here's what I have so far:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application implements CommandLineRunner {

private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Application.class);

public static void main(String args[]) {
    SpringApplication.run(Application.class);
}

@Override
public void run(String... strings) throws Exception {
    ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(
            "curl",
            "-k",   //  "-s",
            "https://website.com:8443/Service/a/1234");

    pb.directory(new File("c:\\users\\axxxxxx"));
    pb.redirectErrorStream(true);
    Process p = pb.start();
    InputStream is = p.getInputStream();

    FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream("c:\\temp\\output.json");
    // System.out.println("In main");

    String line;
    BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(is);
    byte[] bytes = new byte[100];
    int numberBytesRead;
    while ((numberBytesRead = bis.read(bytes, 0, 100)) != -1) {

        outputStream.write(bytes, 0, numberBytesRead);
        Arrays.fill(bytes, (byte) 0);

    }

    outputStream.flush();
    outputStream.close();
```

Thanks to anyone who takes a look at this

Comment: Why can't you use HttpURLConnection?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure why we haven't tried this. We do have a lot of authentication in place for each request, so curl -k bypasses that.

That could be the only reason I can think of.